# creating sql query for selecting multiple data

Tags: sql-server-2008

i need a sql query for my table tbl1

sample contents of the table like this

```
                        serial   ida    idb        
                          1        1       2             
                          2        1       3              
                          3        3       7             
                          4        3       6              
                          5        2       4               
                          6        2       6
```

.

in the table tbl1  column ida and idb are related  like 1 is related with 2 and 3 , 2 is related with 4 and 6

ida value 1 s related data is 2 and 3  and i want to select the  related data of   1' s related data (2 and 3).

2 and 3 s related data is 7, 6 and 4, 6.  so the output will be (7,6,4)
. i need a sql query to display this out put. can anyone share some idea how to do that ..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT idb FROM tbl1 WHERE ida = 2 OR ida = 3;
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: no first select 1 s value which is 2 , 3  and then select 2 and 3 s distinct value

Comment: Ah OK - now I see the complexity. So you want to start with "1" and then traverse the whole dependency tree? Will have a thought about it, but am doubting that this can be done in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Corrected determining child branches of the hierarchy.

This may be of some use:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Table as table ( serial int identity, ida int, idb int )
insert into @Table ( ida, idb ) values
  ( 1, 2 ), ( 1, 3 ),
  ( 3, 7 ), ( 3, 6 ),
  ( 2, 4 ), ( 2, 6 )

select * from @Table

-- Demonstrate recursive query.
; with CTE as (
  -- Start with ida = 1.
  select serial, ida, idb, 1 as depth, path = cast( right( '000000' + cast( ida as varchar(6) ), 6 ) as varchar(1024) )
    from @Table
    where ida = 1
  union all
  -- Add each row related to the most recent selected row(s).
  select T.serial, T.ida, T.idb, C.depth + 1, cast( C.path + right( '000000' + cast( T.ida as varchar(6) ), 6 ) as varchar(1024) )
    from CTE as C inner join
      @Table as T on T.ida = C.idb
  )
-- Show everything.
select *
  from CTE

-- Repeat the recursive query.
; with CTE as (
  -- Start with ida = 1.
  select serial, ida, idb, 1 as depth, path = cast( right( '000000' + cast( ida as varchar(6) ), 6 ) as varchar(1024) )
    from @Table
    where ida = 1
  union all
  -- Add each row related to the most recent selected row(s).
  select T.serial, T.ida, T.idb, C.depth + 1, cast( C.path + right( '000000' + cast( T.ida as varchar(6) ), 6 ) as varchar(1024) )
    from CTE as C inner join
      @Table as T on T.ida = C.idb
  )
-- Select only the deepest children.
select distinct idb
  from CTE as C
  where not exists ( select 42 from CTE where left( path, len( C.path ) ) = C.path and len( path ) > len( C.path ))
  order by idb
```

Left as an exercise is pivoting the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct idb from tbl1 where ida in (select idb from tbl1 where ida = 1)
```